# Getting data from database on pageload jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

can any one help me please

What Im trying to do is a phone app using HTML5, JQUERY, Json and PHP. I cannot use PHP pages in this as I will be packaging it with Phone Gap Cloud Compliler.

I have tried using many scripts and suggestions that I have researched on the internet but cannot seem to get this to work.

On the page I need to retrieve data from the database there are 6 text boxes or divs I wish to populate using a on page ajax request to a PHP processing page that gets the required data and forms it into a Json string, the following scripts will show where I am at presently.

PHP Page:- this works as far as getting the data from the database and from the research I have done succssefully parces it into a Json format

PHP Script **********************************************

```
<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php';

header("Content-Type: application/json");   //this will tell the browser to send a json object back to client not text/html (as default)


session_start();



$return_arr = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `autumnTerm`";       //query
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $row['term1start'] = date('d-m-y', strtotime($row['term1start']));
        $row['term1finish'] = date('d-m-y', strtotime($row['term1finish']));
        $row['term2start'] = date('d-m-y', strtotime($row['term2start']));      
        $row['term2finish'] = date('d-m-y', strtotime($row['term2finish']));


    $row_array['term1start'] = $row['term1start'];
    $row_array['term1finish'] = $row['term1finish'];
    $row_array['term2start'] = $row['term2start'];
    $row_array['term2finish'] = $row['term2finish'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);     

    }


  echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

this returns the following json :-

**[{"term1start":"01-04-15","term1finish":"02-04-15","term2start":"03-04-15","term2finish":"04-04-15"}]**

which I believe to be the right format.

The Jquery:-

```
<script>
```

**I think I am right in believing that document ready should run the jquery script on page load**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

**the processing page address which is associated to a variable**

```
    var url = "http://www.newberylodge.co.uk/webapp/includes/retrieveAutumn.inc.php";
```

**The ajax request defining the request elements**

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
cache: false,
url: url,
dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {

         $('#termoneError').text('The page has been successfully loaded');
      },
      error: function() {
         $('#termoneError').text('An error occurred');
      }
});//ajax request   
 });//ready function    
</script>
```

If anyone would be so kind as to helping me figure this out I would be most greatful, I have been trying to resolve this for over a week now

I havent posted the html trying not to swamp the question with code, but if its needed I will put it up on request

Comment: what code is inside of `retrieveAutumn.inc.php`? is it the PHP code you have added above which returns the json?

Comment: try removing `dataType: "json",` from your ajax call

Comment: @ M.Doyle that has resolved the crossdomain error ty

Comment: no problem, is your code working now?

Comment: @M.Doyle  im still not getting the text responses in my div to say success or error, the console log errors have now been resolved

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
cache: false,
url: url,
 dataType: "json",
  success: function() {
      console.log()
     $('#termoneError').text('The page has been successfully loaded');
  },
  error: function() {
     $('#termoneError').text('An error occurred');
  }
});//ajax request   
 });//ready function    
 </script>
```

and try to see the console is there any error?

Comment: these are following comments i get in console                                                                                                     ReferenceError: finish is not defined                 term.html:121:1
ReferenceError: insetday is not defined            term.html:125:1
ReferenceError: url is not defined                     term.html:16:0

Comment: I just realised I copied what you posted and didnt add the var in, so apart from the inset day and finish references I get this :                                                                                                 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.newberylodge.co.uk/webapp/includes/retrieveAutumn.inc.php?_=1428329407560. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: im still not getting a success or error in the assigned div

Comment: i have now resolved all the console log errors but still not getting success or error in my asigned div

Answer (score 0):

you should try for the error Cross-Origin Request Blocked to put proper header

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');    
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

the rest code its ok

Comment: i found a line to add in to the script that resolved the crossdomain error    ' url = 'proxy.php?url='+url: '

Comment: would i need to add all of these header statements to the php page or just one of them